# NSStackView has incorrect view spacing

Tags: cocoa

I have been playing around with NSStackView (on OS X 10.9.4) and am a bit stuck. Essentially, I am creating a footer view and adding a stack view to this footer. I would like a few items grouped to the left of the footer and a couple of items grouped to the right. I figured this could be done assigning the views to the leading and trailing gravities as needed. However, I don't seem to be able to get the desired effect.

```
NSView* footerView = [[NSView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
footerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.footerView = footerView;

NSStackView* stackView = [[NSStackView alloc] init];
stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.stackView = stackView;
[self.footerView addSubview:stackView];

NSTextField* firstTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
firstTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
firstTextField.bezeled = NO;
firstTextField.editable = NO;
firstTextField.stringValue = @"One";
self.firstTextField = firstTextField;
[self.stackView addView:firstTextField inGravity:NSStackViewGravityLeading];

NSTextField* secondTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
secondTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
secondTextField.bezeled = NO;
secondTextField.editable = NO;
secondTextField.stringValue = @"Two";
self.secondTextField = secondTextField;
[self.stackView addView:secondTextField
              inGravity:NSStackViewGravityLeading];

NSTextField* thirdTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
thirdTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
thirdTextField.bezeled = NO;
thirdTextField.editable = NO;
thirdTextField.stringValue = @"Three";
self.thirdTextField = thirdTextField;
[self.stackView addView:thirdTextField inGravity:NSStackViewGravityLeading];

NSTextField* fourthTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
fourthTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
fourthTextField.bezeled = NO;
fourthTextField.editable = NO;
fourthTextField.stringValue = @"Four";
self.fourthTextFeild = fourthTextField;
[self.stackView addView:fourthTextField
              inGravity:NSStackViewGravityTrailing];

NSTextField* fifthTextField = [[NSTextField alloc] init];
fifthTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
fifthTextField.bezeled = NO;
fifthTextField.editable = NO;
fifthTextField.stringValue = @"Five";
self.fifthTextField = fifthTextField;
[self.stackView addView:fifthTextField
              inGravity:NSStackViewGravityTrailing];

[self.window.contentView addSubview:footerView];

NSDictionary* views = @{
    @"footerView" : self.footerView,
    @"stackView" : self.stackView
};
[self.window.contentView
    addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                       constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[footerView(==30)]|"
                                           options:0
                                           metrics:nil
                                             views:views]];

[self.window.contentView
    addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                       constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[footerView]|"
                                           options:0
                                           metrics:nil
                                             views:views]];
[self.footerView
    addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                       constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[stackView]-|"
                                           options:0
                                           metrics:nil
                                             views:views]];
[self.footerView
    addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint
                       constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[stackView]|"
                                           options:0
                                           metrics:nil
                                             views:views]];
```

If I am only adding the first three textFields, then they are all grouped together correctly in the leading area. 
[image: Only leading area views]

But, when I add the trailing area views, the views in the leading area jump towards the trailing area
[image: Leading and Trailing Views]

From the documentation of NSStackView for the spacer property, I see

> In combination, these constraints result in the following typical
>   stack view behavior: In a stack view whose hasEqualSpacing property is
>   set to NO (the default) and whose hugging priority is left at
>   NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow (the default), views within a gravity area
>   remain a fixed distance from each other (equal to the value of the
>   spacing property), and the distance between gravity areas grows and
>   shrinks as the stack view grows and shrinks along its layout direction
>   axis.

But, this doesn't seem to be happening. The spacing between views within a gravity area (leading) is not constant, and, instead of growing/shrinking the distance between gravity areas, it seems to set it to the spacer distance.

What I would like is for One, Two, Three to appear on the left of the footer (spaced by the default distance) and Four, Five to appear on the right of the footer. I could try and get to this, by using two different stack views (one for leading area and another for the trailing area), but, was thinking this should be possible with a single stack view and gravity areas. Would appreciate some guidance on this. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if an `NSStackView` is appropriate to use for this. Wouldn't it be easier to arrange the views manually using some basic autolayout constraints? Why do you need an `NSStackView` ?

Comment: Per the docs - `A stack view employs Auto Layout (the system’s constraint-based layout feature) to arrange and align an array of views according to your specification.` It just seemed like an easier alternative than manually specifying all the constraints (although, as you said, it's simple enough in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for the `spacing` property of `NSStackView` show that the inter-gravity-area spacing is set to the `spacing` value (default 8 points) with the stack view's configured hugging priority in that orientation (which defaults to `NSLayoutPriorityDefaultLow`).

If the content hugging priority of the text fields is lower than that, then the auto layout system will prefer to stretch one of them rather than the inter-gravity-area spacing. That's why one of the text fields was stretched as shown in your question. (If the text fields have equal content hugging priorities, which text field gets stretched is arbitrary and can change at any time.)

If the content hugging priority of the text fields is equal to the hugging priority of the stack view, then it's arbitrary what gets stretched. It could be one of the text fields or it could be the inter-gravity-area spacing.

You want to make the text fields have higher content hugging priority, as you've indicated in your answer. It doesn't need to be `NSLayoutPriorityDragThatCanResizeWindow`. It can be anything higher than the stack view's hugging priority.

That has nothing to do with the window being restricted from shrinking, as you report in your answer.

If you want the stack view to allow itself to shrink narrower than the size indicated by its subviews and the spacing between them, you have two options. First, you can set its clipping resistance priority to something lower than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut`, using `-setClippingResistancePriority:forOrientation:`. That will cause the stack view to allow views to be clipped or detached. Which of those things happens depends on the visibility priority of the views, as set by `setVisibilityPriority:forView:`. By default, all views have visibility priority of `NSStackViewVisibilityPriorityMustHold`, which means they won't detach but will be clipped.

So, if you want the views to be detached, you should change their visibility priorities. You should order the priorities to indicate which views you want detached first (lower visibility priority) relative to others (higher).

The other approach would be to set the compression resistance priority of the subviews to be lower than `NSLayoutPriorityWindowSizeStayPut`. That means that the auto layout system will compress the text fields, typically truncating them with an ellipsis ("…"). You would want to order the compression resistance priorities of the text fields to determine the order in which they compress, or else it will be arbitrary (and could even change from moment to moment). You would probably also want to set a minimum width constraint on the text fields since at some point it looks bad to have the text field be visible but with no room to show any meaningful content.

You can combine the two approaches by having the compression resistance of the text fields be below the stack view's clipping resistance. The minimum width constraints of the text fields would presumably be high or even required; in any case, higher than the stack view's clipping resistance. So, as the window and stack view shrink, a text field would compress until it reaches its minimum width, then the next one would compress, etc. When all of the text fields are at their minimum width, the stack view would clip or detach them (in visibility priority order) until they fit again.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have it fixed (in a manner of speaking), by setting the content hugging priority of each textfield to NSLayoutPriorityDragThatCanResizeWindow.

```
[firstTextField
    setContentHuggingPriority:NSLayoutPriorityDragThatCanResizeWindow
               forOrientation:NSLayoutConstraintOrientationHorizontal];
```

[image: Correct Layout]
However, this now restricts the window frame to a minimum size (one that will allow display of all the textfields). It doesn't allow clipping or dropping of the textfields.